# Cannot access my web app deployed to azure service fabric

Tags: web-deployment, azure-service-fabric

I can access my web API in local service fabric by URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/values
```

I published it to Azure using Visual Studio and cannot access it at:

```
http://<myservice>.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com:8080/api/values
```

I have reverse proxy enabled. The fabric explorer shows everything is healthy and my application is hosted in three nodes.
Am I using the wrong URL? Should I configure a port in load balancer?

Comment: Is the port open in Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things worked out after I added port 8080 to "Load balancing rules" in the load balancer.